# right align DIV to right edge of bootstrap container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.  I have a row with 2 DIVs containing text of different font height. The 1st DIV is col-md-9 contains large text, the 2nd col-md-3 contains small text. I need to align the 2nd DIV to far right and to the bottom edge of the row.  No manually positioning with top, right, bottom, left is allowed.  Here is the markup.  Thanks
[image]

```html
<div class="container">

  ...

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-9">
      <large>
        <a class="titleLink" ui-sref="login">
          <span ng-cloak>
                {{vm.serviceName}} - {{vm.consults.length | number}} Consults
              </span>
        </a>
        <span ng-cloak class="label label-primary">{{vm.ActiveCount}} Active</span>
        <span ng-cloak class="label label-warning">{{vm.PendingCount}} Pending</span>
        <span ng-cloak class="label label-danger">{{vm.PartialResultsCount}} Incomplete/PR</span>
      </large>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-3">
      <small>
          <span ng-cloak>Data Extracted: {{vm.dataExtracted}}</span>
        </small>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or image of what you want?

Comment: The image is added

Comment: no positioning style is allowed because the alignment is jagged in smaller devices.

Comment: try setting `padding-bottom` to 0px of the right div

Comment: what about `.pull-right` ?